# Positioning labels in Tikz, with pgf 3.0.1

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been using Tikz for some time, and have some macros that have been working well... so far. It seems they broke since pgf updated to 3.0.1.

In particular, I have some macros to put text in a specific point in a figure, and to position it in a specific place in that figure. For instance, the following macro used to put text in the right side of some specific place:

```
\newcommand{\tkzputrghtext}[2]{
  \node[label distance=-10pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    minimum height=0pt,minimum width=0pt,
    outer xsep=0pt,outer ysep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,
    label=right:#2] at (#1){};}
```

Now, the "right" argument to label is not considered a position argument anymore; it is now treated as part of the label (so all labels are of the form "right:...").

How should I do this, in a way that is more robust to pgf versions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\newcommand{\tkzputrghtext}[2]{
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        minimum height=0pt,minimum width=0pt,
        label={[label distance=-10pt]right:#2}] at (#1) {};}
```

I suppose, that among options of your node to label belong only `label distance` and others to node. For it is enough to determine `inner` and `outer` separation only once ... so I omit their declaration for `xsep` and `ysep`.

I do not understand why you use an empty node for placing labels. This you can do this by node itself.

Comment: coordinates can also have labels as they are nodes. so you don't need any of that stuff